# MySQL Combine Multiple Queries

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Here is a sample table.

```
ColZero | ColOne | RoColTwo
--------+--------+--------
   1    | one    | tag1
   2    | two    | tag1
   3    | three  | tag2
   4    | four   | tag2
   5    | five   | tag3
```

I have the following query.

```
SELECT `ColOne` FROM `Table` WHERE `ColTwo` = ? ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1;
```

I'd like to select multiple rows, using multiple values of `RowTwo` in a single query but each row still has to be random.

This involves merging a variable number of instances of this query into a new, single query.

How can this be done in one query? (I am trying to make this as quick as possible, so getting it all done in one request, as opposed to 10-30 requests is a big plus.)

Comment: Are you confusing the terms "Row" and "Col"?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the most efficient way to do what you want is to use variables:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             (@rn := if(@r = RowTwo, @rn + 1,
                        if(@r := RowTow, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      FROM `Table` t CROSS JOIN
           (SELECDT @r := '', @rn := 0) params
      WHERE `RowTwo` IN (?, ?, ?)
      ORDER BY RowTwo, rand()
     ) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

If you don't want to use dynamic SQL and you want to support an indefinite number of values, you might consider:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(RowTwo, ?) > 0
```

In any case, naming columns ROW causes (for me at least) cognitive dissonance.

Comment: Ty! Oops, fixed the naming. I'm struggling to understand some of this. What goes in place of `params`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  The `?` are the values that you want to check `RowTwo` for.  You can leave out that `where` clause to get a random row for each value.

Answer (score 1):

You could use union  using different value for RowTo

```
SELECT `RowOne` FROM `Table` WHERE `RowTwo` = ? ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1

union 

SELECT `RowOne` FROM `Table` WHERE `RowTwo` = ? ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1

union 

SELECT `RowOne` FROM `Table` WHERE `RowTwo` = ? ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1

union 

SELECT `RowOne` FROM `Table` WHERE `RowTwo` = ? ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1 ;
```

Comment: Ty! The only problem is that forces the selection of a fixed number of rows.

Comment: yIn someway yes   .. you can only change  change the limit and the number of union ..